# play loud ring tone/music irrespective of which profile it is in

Tags: android

i want to play any ring tone/song music irrespective of whether it is in silent mode or vibration mode or any other mode.
the code i am using to play a ring tone is

```
 Uri ringtoneUri =  RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
                Ringtone ringtoneSound;
                ringtoneSound=RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, ringtoneUri);
                if (ringtoneSound != null) {
                    ringtoneSound.play();
                }
```

but ring tone plays only when mobile volume is high. is there any way to increase the volume of android device ? so that i can increase the volume of my android device and then run the above code.

Comment: Don't you think that it's hardly the expected behaviour for a user hearing a loud ringtone while her phone is in silent mode?

Comment: No it isn't. If the user decides to turn off sound on his device, one should not bypass that wish. Imagine how that would be abused by some people...

Comment: just for example. consider android manager. when phone is lost, we can call that device. and that device rings loudly irrespective of which mode it is in.

Answer (score 1):

This should work to set the volume if the phone is a profile authorizing sound.

```
public void setAlarmVolume(int iVol) {
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (am!=null) {
        int maxVol = am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
        int volume = (maxVol*iVol)/100;
        am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, volume, 0);
    }
}
```

iVol is the volume in percent (0 to 100).

Keep in mind that if the device is set on vibration only or on silence, you still won't get sound, and quite rightfully so. You can't bypass the user's wish not to have sound.

Comment: Fixed. This was specific for my application.

Comment: ok . so is it advisable to play any song using music player ? because music play songs in any mode(silent/vibrate/general). ?

Comment: If you want people to uninstall your application immediately... you can do that, that's a pretty good way. They will give you one chance to annoy them when their phone is in silent mode, not two. It can possibly even get you kicked from the play store.

Comment: ya . but how to do that ? how to play any song in music player with full volume ?